# Looking to purchase Android NFC Tags

Tags: android, nfc

I am looking to buy some NFC tags that is compatible with Android Nexus S.  I understand Gingerbread supports Type 1,2,3,4.  I need tags that are readable and writable and has overwrite protection.

I've heard about touchatag and the price is low.  Anyone know what type it is (or which ISO it is based on)?  I can't seem to find this information online.

If anyone has success with tags from other stores. Please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

The touchatag Tags are Mifare Ultralight tags (NFC Type 2). Capacity is low, around 46 bytes when used with Ndef. Touchabag does not specify which kind of Ultralight they sell. If you are lucky they sell Ultralight-C which has a little bit more memory.

These tags can be write protected.

Another option for tags that support write protection are Innovision Jewel tags. (NFC Type 1). These are currently hard to get because Innovision was recently sold to a different company and the future of tag production is unclear.

Type3 is based on the Felica standard and these are very hard to get. Felica tags fresh from the factory aren't usable for NFC because they first have to be formatted. How this is done is confidential information and not part of the NFC standard. I got my Type3 tags directly from someone who works at Sony/Felica networks. Type3 tags could in theory write protected, but how this is done is again confidential (e.g. Android can't do it).

For a nice Type4 tag try to get Mifare Desfire. These are ISO14443-A tags, they have lots of memory (1k to 4k) they aren't write protectable. (again, technically you can write protect them, but it's not part of the NFC standard, however if you get you hands on the Desfire documentation you will see how it is done using low-level IsoDep commands.

Last option is the Mifare Classic. Easy to buy, but the NFC standard does not define a standard way to write protect them. However, writing your own write protection is easy once you've read the specification.

Answer (score 1):

My company, tagstand, sells NFC tags and stickers at [www.tagstand.com](http://www.tagstand.com). We sell Mifare Ultralight and Mifare 1K stickers

The Mifare 1K stickers hold about 700 bytes of data but can't be made read only. They're great and forgiving for tinkering with though, especially if you want to try out different data types. You could fit a vCard, smart poster, and larger URLs on them with ease. They work with the Nexus S but might not work with all future android or NFC devices.

The Mifare Ultralight stickers we sell are more standard. They only have 48 bytes of usable user data, but are perfect for storing URLs and phone numbers. They're also NFC Forum Type 2 compliant, meaning that they'll work on any current and foreseeable NFC device

Comment: Just curious : If you have a "public" poster with a 1k Mifare - what's to stop someone mischievously overwritting your original data (eg URL) with an incorrect one ?

Answer (score 1):

The press release released this morning by Identive Group states that they launched a new website where you can purchase type 1, 2 and 4 nfc tags.  I checked out the site - it's decent - looks like they also have nfc readers and an sdk.

The NFC tags in the store are here:  http://www.identivenfc.com/google-nfc-tags.htm

More about Identive & NFC: http://www.nearfieldcommunicationsworld.com/2011/04/13/36986/google-chooses-identive-to-deliver-nfc-tags-for-places-campaign/

Not sure if this helps, but at least it gives you a place to start looking :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get tags for example from a company called ToP Tunniste. They also offer tools for development (ie. devkits, software etc.). There even seems to be a free sample campaign going on at the moment: http://www.toptunniste.fi/topshop/product_details.php?p=333&c=47.